# Difference between using resgen and Resource files for localization

Tags: .net, localization

I've been reading a few articles about localization in .NET and it seems there's a couple of different approaches. Some of the articles are quite old though.

Some articles suggest putting key value pairs into a text file and generating a .resources file using resgen. Others suggest using Resource files using the naming convention .en-US as an example, and then using some code (shown below) to get the strings I need depending on the culture.

ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Are there better approaches for this? I feel like it's too easy. Am I just scratching the surface in terms of localization? Surley there must be more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't know anything about resgen, but the App_LocalResources and the App_GlobalResources folders are built in and do a great job.

I really like the approach of using something like this

-**About.aspx**
-**Default.aspx**
-App_LocalResources/
-App_LocalResources/**About.aspx.fr.resx**
-App_LocalResources/**About.aspx.resx**
-App_LocalResources/**Default.aspx.fr.resx**
-App_LocalResources/**Default.aspx.resx**

### EDIT:

here is some good [info on Localization](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx) in ASP.NET